# Dart - Isolate Cross Window Communication

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

Is cross-window communication possible with Dart isolates?  Here is my scenario: User opens web site in browser window A and window A spawns a new isolate.  The user then clicks a link that creates a new tab and opens browser window B (assume the link is in the same domain, etc...).  Can browser window B send and receive messages from the isolate spawned by browser window A, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Cross window communication is not possible using isolates messaging alone. However you can do cross window communication using **postMessage** as described [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/cross-window-messaging/) and then set up message handlers that communicates with each isolate (there by using postMessage as a sort of message bus between each isolate).